# Opengeosuite 4 unable to open psql

Tags: postgis, boundless-suite

When I try and open psql from the postgis menu in opengeosuite 4 on the Mac I get the following error message.

“psql” can’t be opened because PostGIS is not allowed to open documents in Terminal.

Anyone know how to cure this error.

Comment: weird. what version of osx?

Comment: I am using Mavericks

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with Mavericks, introduced by a security feature that disallows applescript to run. We're looking into it but for now the workaround is to:

1. Install the CLI tools package
2. Put /usr/local/opengeo/bin on the PATH
3. Run psql from the terminal manually

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't a new bug, it happened with mountain lion as well.